# summing up rows which are not selected in where clause

Tags: sql

Sample data in the table with 4 columns :

```
1st row           A1    B1  C1  D1

2nd row           A1    B2  C2  D2

3rd row           A1    B3  C3  D3

4th row           A2    B1  C4  D4

5th row           A2    B4  C5  D5

6th row           A3    B1  C6  D6
```

I want to **select all the column**s for a row which satisfies condition `COL-B = B1`
In addition, I want sum of `COL-D` for each selected value of `COL-A`

Output data

```
1st row           A1    B1  C1  D1+D2+D3

2nd row           A2    B1  C4  D4+D5

3rd row           A3    B1  C6  D6
```

I am not able to figure out how to sum up rows which are not selected in where clause. Please help

Comment: if they aren't selected, they can't be summed

Comment: sorry i am a noob with sql but is there no way this can be done by joining same table twice. Forgot to mention that COL-A and COL-B are primary keys

Comment: maybe i don't understand the question, disregard my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the following two should work:

```
SELECT A,B,C,(select SUM(D) from Table t2 where t2.A = t.A)
FROM Table t
WHERE t.B = 'B2'
```

or:

```
SELECT t.A,t.B,t.C,t2.D
FROM Table t
   inner join
       (select A,SUM(D) as D from Table) t2
      on
          t.A = t2.A
WHERE
    t.B = 'B2'
```

Which one would perform better generally depends on how many rows are in the table in total, how many have `B`=`'B2'`, and how many then related rows (with a matching `A` value) exist.

---

Or, another one:

```
SELECT A,MAX(CASE WHEN B='B2' THEN B END) as B,MAX(CASE WHEN B='B2' THEN C END) as C,SUM(D) as D
FROM Table
GROUP BY A
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN B='B2' THEN B END) = 'B2'
```

Which might be more efficient (should only result in a single table scan - here I'm assuming that most rows in the table should end up in the result set)

Comment: thanks a lot.. this was most useful.. I will go with first one as the number of rows fetched will be generally much leeser than the total present in the table

Answer (score 1):

You need to use sub query and grouping if you want sum and filter condition in single query like below :

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (Col1 VARCHAR(10), Col2 VARCHAR(10), Col3 VARCHAR(10), Col4 INT)

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('A1','B1','C1',1) 
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('A1','B2','C2',1)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('A1','B3','C3',1)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('A2','B1','C4',1)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('A2','B4','C5',1)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('A3','B1','C6',1)

SELECT  Col1, 
        (SELECT TOP 1 Col2 FROM @Table WHERE Col1 = MainTable.Col1) Col2,
        (SELECT TOP 1 Col3 FROM @Table WHERE Col1 = MainTable.Col1) Col3,
        SUM(Col4) AS Total 
FROM @Table MainTable
GROUP BY Col1
```

But here your condition of filter for B1 will not satisfy for every case. This is just output which you mentioned. If there is no any record for example Col1=A4 then it will get whatever value in col2 like record =>> 'A4','B2','C6',1, it will return B2.

**UPDATE :** Ref. from Damien_The_Unbeliever's post

For A4 case I think you need to do like :

```
SELECT  Col1,
        Col2,
        Col3,
        (SELECT SUM(Col4) FROM @Table t2 WHERE t2.Col1 = t.Col1) 
FROM @Table t 
WHERE t.Col2 = 'B1'
```

Comment: thanks but I will have a row 'A4' which might not have 'B1'. This won't work :(

Answer (score 0):

If I was solving this problem with SQL, I would first group by column `A` and find the sum of column `D`.

This query will use an inner query and will do a filter for `B='B1'`.

```
select inn.A,inn.sum_d, Tb.B 
from (
    //inner query
    select A, sum(D) sum_d 
    from <table> Ta 
    group by A
) inn,
<table> Tb
where 
//join inner query output to table Tb.w here Ta and Tb are same table with 2 different alias name.
inn.A=Tb.A
and Tb.B= 'B1'
```

This pseudo code should give you desired result.

This may not be an ideal query. But this is the basic logic you are looking for.

Comment: SELECT B.COL-A,INN.SUM_D FROM { SELECT COL-A, SUM(COL-D) SUM_D FROM TABLE TA GROUP BY COL-A } INN, TABLE B WHERE B.COL-A = INN.COL-A AND B.COL-B = 'B1'    .. I used this but I am getting SQLCODE -104 saying '{' is illegal..I am running this on IBM SPUFI as I need this in a COBOL DB2 program.. Is that reason.. I have never seen a query in FROM clause being used before

Comment: oops the Curly bracket is the issue. you should use ordinary Bracket. i will correct the syntax